# Why not importing the this class? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-errors

I try to follow this tutorial

[link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/easy-fluid-keyboard-movement-in-as3-with-the-input-class--active-10467)

**This is my code:**

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.ShaderInput;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import Input;                               //here is a problem
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            square = new Sprite();
            square.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
            square.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
            square.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - square.width / 2;
            square.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - square.height / 2;
            addChild(square);

          Input.initialize(stage);     //here is another problem

            //Add the refresh loop
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, refresh);
        }

         private function refresh(e:Event):void {
             trace("gigi");
        }
```

I receive this error:

```
Line 42 1120: Access of undefined property Input.
Line 7  1172: Definition Input could not be found.
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs?
Unable to import class tutorial Input but it is used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is obviously a Custom class, create it.

Answer (score 2):

In the tutorial, there is a "Download Attachment" button which downloads a ZIP containing the Input class. Add this to your src folder.